# The divisor $D=Y_1+Y_2$ is not smooth if $Y_1$ intersects $Y_2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $D$ be a divisor on a non-singular projective variety $X$.

If $D=Y_1+Y_2$ for two prime divisors $Y_1, Y_2$, then $D$ is smooth iff $Y_1$ does not intersect $Y_2$ and both are smooth?

My reasoning is that if $Y_1\cap Y_2\not=\emptyset$, then around the intersection we have a defining equation $f=f_1f_2$. But then using the Jacobi criterion for smoothness we find that at the intersection $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0$ for all $i$, and hence $Y$ is not smooth.

In particular on $X=\mathbb{P}^n$ the only smooth sections of $\mathcal{O}_X(d)$ correspond to irreducible, smooth, homogeneous degree $d$ polynomials. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: You should write that that $D_1,D_2$ are distinct **prime divisors**, not principal divisors.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg:  good point. Amazing how I can completely fail to notice these details...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you, that is what I meant.

Comment: @Nefertiti As small addition: in the case of $\mathbb{P}^1$ all sections are reducible into linear homogeneous parts, in which case the corresponding divisor is smooth if there are no repeated factors?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg As small addition: in the case of $\mathbb{P}^1$ all sections are reducible into linear homogeneous parts, in which case the corresponding divisor is smooth if there are no repeated factors?

Comment: Dear user2520938: If the base field $k$ has characteristic zero  then a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ on $\mathbb P^1_k$ (aka global section of $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P_k^1}(d)$) has a smooth zero set if and only if it has no repeated factor. In characteristic $p$ however this is no longer true: over $k=\mathbb F_p(t)$ the homogeneous polynomial $x^p+ty^p$ is irreducible but defines a non smooth subscheme of $\mathbb P^1_k$.